# Applet won't start using Applet runner from Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet, japplet

I have an applet, which I can run fine from the browser, but when I try to run it from the Applet configuration in Intellij Idea, it doesn't start because it can't find some classes. The definition of applet in the page looks like this(from the startApp.jsp which I use for starting it):

```
<applet mayscript archive="/library1.jar.pack.gz, /library2.jar.pack.gz, .." 
   code="com.company.library1.MainApplet" codebase="/"
   type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6.0_20" align = "top" border = "0" height = "860" hspace = "0" width = "1250" vspace  = "0">
   <--some parameters-->        
</applet>
```

The class not found is `MainApplet`, which is inside the `library1.jar.pack.gz`

Is there some way to make it work also from the applet viewer and not from the web page?
I don't get any other exception than this:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Djava.security.policy=/home/user/SW/idea-IU-133.696/bin/appletviewer.policy -Djnlp.packEnabled=true -Didea.launcher.port=7535 
-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/user/SW/idea-IU-133.696/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath 
/home/user/SW/idea-IU-133.696/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain 
sun.applet.AppletViewer http://localhost:8080/startApp.jsp
load: class com.company.library1.MainApplet not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.library1.MainApplet
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(AppletClassLoader.java:219)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:152)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:633)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:793)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:722)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Applet Viewer in IntelliJ IDEA is geared towards running applets you are working on in your project. That said, you can run one from a library JAR. Looking at the first four lines of your output, I am not seeing the `library1` on your class path. Thus java cannot find the `MainApplet` class. In the Applet Viewer configuration dialog there is a "*Use classpath of module*" option. Set that to the IDEA module that has the `library1` dependency in its classpath (i.e. in its list of dependencies). As a caveat, while I know it will work for a JAR file, I'm not sure about a Pack200 file off hand. I'd be curious though.

Comment: Thanks for reply. library1 is listed in the `archive` attribute of the applet tag. It works like that from the browser and in the intellij idea, I'm providing URL, so it should be the same. The MainApplet(library1) is not a part of my project and I don't have sources for it. I only have a packed jar.

Comment: I _suspect_ the issue is that IDEA is not able to handle the Pack200 (i.e. *.pack.gz) format. Open IDEA Feature request [IDEA-73259](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73259) appears to confirm this. I recommend you vote for it.I'm not that familiar with Pack200, so I'm not sure offhand if the .pack.gz file gets signed, or if the jar gets signed and then put in the pack. If the latter, you could download it, unpack it, create a "empty" IDEA module, add the unpacked jar as a module dependency, then use that as the module classpath.

Comment: Upon closer reading, I see IDEA-73259 is about creating Pack200 files. I recommend you open a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) for support of _reading_ Pack200 files.